# Lyx question sheet with answers. How to export to PDF only the questions?

Tags: lyx

I have an exercise written as a Lyx document, with questions followed by my (TA) solutions. What's the best way to export only the questions to PDF? I don't want to have to create a separate document each time (Any change I make would have to be done in both).

Comment: Insert > Branch & Document > Settings ... > Branches

Comment: Branches are ideal for this. I suggest @Fran writes an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LyX allows inserting boxes of text with custom labels in
<kbd>Insert</kbd> → <kbd>Branch</kbd> →  <kbd>Insert New Branch ...</kbd>

After a new branch is created, the label (e.g. "Question") will be available in the same menu, so you can make another boxes with the same label (that is, in the same branch).

[image: mwe]

Then, in  <kbd>Document</kbd>  → <kbd>Settings ...</kbd> →  <kbd>Branches</kbd> you can <kbd>(De)activate</kbd> each of these branches. Here you can also change the color of the boxes and add more branches.

Note that activated branch contents are inserted in the LaTeX source without leaving traces that is optional text, while  deactivated branches will be completely removed from the source. Therefore, branches not only allow to make PDF versions, but also  LaTeX source versions.